# Sentence structure with "ama lo que haces"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, verbos, objetos-directos

So I believe the line below translates to, *Love what you do*

I'm not entirely sure why the *lo* is needed but more than that I'm confused by its position in the sentence. I though direct object pronouns either come before the verb or can be attached to the end of an infinite verb (if there are two verbs)

> Ama lo que haces

Comment: Translation is correct, other examples are:  
- Mira lo que hiciste. *Look what you have done*
- Escucha lo que dijo. *Hear what he/she has said*

Comment: It is easier to see the parallel with English if you translate it as Love that which you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a different *lo*. The one you refer to is the [3rd person personal pronoun](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NWnohQu), which is used to refer to something or someone mentioned before and different from the one who speaks or writes:

> No te pediré perdón, aunque no te **lo** creas.
>   A su señoría **lo** aprecian mucho.

But in "Ama lo que haces," *lo* is the [neuter form of the articles *el, la*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ESraxkH). It is used:

- Before adjectives.

  > Le encanta **lo** étnico.
- Before complements with the preposition *de*.

  > No me explicaste **lo** de ayer.
- Before relative clauses (as in your example).

  > ¿No te interesa **lo** que dice?

It has other uses you can check in the DLE link above (ckeck the definitions 9-11 marked as `art. deter. n.`).

Comment: so lo can be 1) 3rd person personal pronoun & 2) a neutral form of el or la. Nice and confusing :-)

Comment: @mHelpMe it just depends on what comes next (_depende de **lo** que venga después_). :-)

Comment: so if its a verb that comes next is it then a 3rd person personal pronoun otherwise its the other form? Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @mHelpMe ...ish. If it's a verb it's almost always a pronoun, except when it's a participle. Example: _Ver **lo** especificado más arriba_ (See what's specified above). _Bueno, **lo** dicho, nos vemos_ (Well, as I said, be seeing you).

Comment: the "el" or "la" in this case are not pronouns, are the translation of the particle "the". or "that"

Comment: when "what" in English is used as a noun then in Spanish has to be translated to "la", "lo" or "el"

Comment: @Mike "what", known in these constructs as a nominal relative, is always translated as neuter gender "lo que".

Comment: I see "lo" as a pronoun and not a determiner. For the rest, I totally agree with you and I've always seen it like that. However, my Spanish language (lengua) teacher wanted us all to say that "lo que" goes altogether as a group, and in fact "lo que" is the translation of the English "what".

Answer (score 1):

The existing answer is great, but since you are feeling confused about the two functions of **lo**, I am going to write a supplementary answer.

If you see it in a sentence, without "que", it's a plain old pronoun.  Examples:

> 1. Préstame tu libro, por favor.  Prometo leerlo rápido.

*Lend me your book, please.  I promise to read it quickly.*

> 2. -- ¿Dónde está mi lápiz?  ¡No lo encuentro!
>
>    -- Está en la mesa, junto al cuaderno.  ¿No lo ves?

*"Where's my pencil?  I can't find it!"*

*"It's on the table, next to the notebook.  Don't you see it?"*

But if you see it with "que", then it's like in your sentence ("Ama lo que haces").  Examples:

> Lo que no entiendo es el tercer problema de página 127. | *What I don't understand is the third problem on page 127.*
>
> Creo que entiendo lo que propones. | *I think I understand what you're proposing.*

As @mdewey commented, it can be helpful to think of it as meaning

> that which

Example:

> I think I understand that which you're proposing.